# Javascript "window.open" code won't work in Internet Explorer 7 or 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, window.open

I am using this chunk of jQuery/Javascript code on my site to open a popup window:

```
$('#change_photo_link').click(function(){
    $id = $('#id').attr('value');

    window.open("photo.upload.php?id=" + $id,"Upload Photo",
    "menubar=no,width=430,height=100,toolbar=no");
});
```

This code works on Firefox and Chrome.  It does not work on IE7 or IE8 (haven't tested IE6).
IE pops up an error on the line `window.open`.  Why?  The error that IE gives is "Invalid Argument" and that's all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's the space in the second parameter that's causing it.  If you use "UploadPhoto" instead of "Upload Photo", it works:

```
$('#change_photo_link').click(function(){
    $id = $('#id').attr('value');

    window.open("photo.upload.php?id=" + $id,"UploadPhoto",
    "menubar=no,width=430,height=100,toolbar=no");
});
```

I can't seem to find any official reasons as to why having a space in the `windowName` parameter of `window.open()` causes an error, but it's likely just an implementation detail. The `windowName` is used as an internal reference, and can be used as a value for a target attribute of an anchor or form, so I guess IE can't handle that internally.  The reference docs for Gecko/Firefox says that this parameter *should* not contain spaces, but clearly current versions of Gecko don't have a problem with it if it does.

Comment: zombat: yeah why is it a problem, isn't that the window title... just figured it had to be toString() because of that.

Comment: It's probably because the second parameter is the *name* of the window, and it's not allowed to contain whitespace

Comment: @Hogan: It's an internal _name_, not a _title_.

Comment: Note that IE will also fail if the second parameter contains "-". For example, "twitter-window" will fail. I love IE so much!

Answer (score 9):

The `windowName` argument can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores (i.e. `[A-Z0-9_]`).

You must change

```
window.open("photo.upload.php?id=" + $id,"Upload Photo",
"menubar=no,width=430,height=100,toolbar=no");
```

to

```
window.open("photo.upload.php?id=" + $id,"Upload_Photo",
"menubar=no,width=430,height=100,toolbar=no");
```

or some other name that doesn't have spaces.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open.