# Why do I see JavaScript variables prefixed with $?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

This is sort of a meta-question.  Many snippets of JavaScript I've seen here on SO are named with a dollar sign prefix (for example, `$id` on the second line of the snippet shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8) question).  I'm not referring to jQuery or other libraries.  I am well aware that this is valid, but it seems awkward to do when not necessary.  Why do people name their variables like this?  Is it just familiarity with a server-side language like PHP carrying over into their JavaScript code?

I thought perhaps it was to identify a variable as being a jQuery object, for example when you save the result of a selection to a variable in order to eliminate duplicate selections later on, but I haven't seen any consistent convention.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Syntactically, the dollar sign itself means nothing -- to the interpreter, it's just another character, like `_` or `q`. But a lot of people using jQuery and other similar frameworks will prefix variables that contain a jQuery object with a $ so that they are easily identified, and thus not mixed up with things like integers or strings. You could just as easily adopt the same convention by prefixing such variables with `jq_` and it would have the same effect.

In effect, it is a crude sort of **[Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)**.

Comment: `In effect, it is a crude sort of Hungarian notation.`  Luckily, I don't see much JavaScript written like `var strHippo = "hippo";`.

Answer (score 4):

I will sometimes prefix a variable name with $ to indicate that it is a jQuery-wrapped element (most often when I'm using `$(this)` in a function a lot, I will assign that to `$this`).

Part of where the lack of convention may come from is people copy-pasting code together that uses different conventions, thus producing inconsistent code.

Also, sometimes (rarely I hope) people who program in PHP a lot will put $'s at the beginning of their variable names out of habit.

Comment: Indicating saved jQuery objects with $ seems like a decent practice.  It's just been baffling when I see it on a variable being used to store a String or some other unrelated type.

Comment: Definitely, it really makes no sense to arbitrarily use `$`s in some places and not in others. Though it would be weird to use it everywhere, too.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the person in that example was just copying the jQuery pattern, or is used to PHP/Perl, without really understanding that it isn't necessary and has no special meaning.

However, I have seen [experienced] programmers use it for variable names that are reserved keywords, such as `$class` or `$this`. Or even for globals. It's really a personal preference more than anything, in that case.

Comment: People copying jQuery without knowing better seems likely.