# window.open not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, window.open

Apparently, this call to `window.open` is not valid under Internet Explorer. The Javascript code on my site is not running, I would assume it is due to that error.

The line it tells me the error is on, is the call to window.open, apparently an argument is not valid there.

```
$('.objeto').click( 
        function() {
            var center   = 'height=380,width=900,top='+((screen.width - 900)/2)+',left='+((screen.height - 380)/2);
            var address = $(this).attr('id');
            window.open (address,'Ver articulo', config=center); 
        }
    );
```

The site runs fine under both Google Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript "window.open" code won't work in Internet Explorer 7 or 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In IE, you can't have spaces in your second variable (the new window's name).

Try:

```
window.open (address,'Ver_articulo', config=center);
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. This is the answer. I'm also having troubles with JQuery compability on IE. It tells me that there is an error on the JQuery code I get from http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js.

Non-Valid argument on line 4031, it says.

Comment: @serv-bot - Well, I already have the Scholar badge. Now, if I also had a green sign next to my answer... :)

Comment: About your jQuery error, that's weird, you should post a new question about that.

Comment: Hahaha, you'll get it. Remember I have to wait 10 minutes until I can vote on the answer. Any ideas on my inquiry? Or should I post another question?

Comment: Note that IE will also fail if the second parameter contains "-". For example, "twitter-window" will fail. I love IE so much!

Answer (score 7):

Also worth re-iterating that IE9 (and possibly below) doesn't like hyphens ('-') in the window name (2nd parameter).

I know one of the comments mentioned this, but it's a bit buried - and it's one tip that just solved an issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what config is, you just need:

```
window.open (address,'VerArticulo', center);
```

Keep in mind though, it looks like your `id` attribute is invalid to get the effect here, you probably want to use something different, e.g. `data-href="urlHere"` on the element, if it's not an anchor already.

Comment: I'm parsing the URL trough the id attribute, since the tags are auto-generated with a php script that gets the information from a mysql table. It's working on all major browsers. Is there a reason why I shouldn't be doing that?

Comment: @serv-bot - Invalid IDs can have all sorts of side-effects and inconsistent behavior, it's better to use an attribute where an href is expected, or at the very least, an invalid ID *isn't* expected.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid ID? The different DIV boxes are generated as such...
 $id = $row['id'];
 echo "<div id='verauto.php?fid=$id' class='objeto'>";
And there is no chance of them being repeated.

Comment: @serv-bot - You can see the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name) : "ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."  So that querystring portion isn't valid :)  It'd be better to use a data attribute, e.g. `data-href="verauto.php?fid=$id"` and `.attr("data-href")` here.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make the corresponding change then, for the sake of using the language right. You have been incredibly helpful, and I was wondering if I could get your insight on this other question I'm about to post. :)

Answer (score 0):

even thou it's kind a late with answer for OP, but for someone else stumbling across this post it might help:

Had exactly same problem as OP after trying to use "window.open" method. It turns out that Chrome is ok with original href tag with URL in it where IE seems to get confused with that. After removing href from link worked spot on.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('a[rel^="external"]').each(function () 
    {
        var externalLink = $(this);
        var externalLinkValue = externalLink.attr("href");
        externalLink.unbind('click');
        externalLink.removeAttr("href");

        externalLink.click(function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            followExtrenalLink = window.open(externalLinkValue,'_blank');
        });

        externalLink.hover(function ()
        {
            externalLink.css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

    });
```