# Window.open not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [window.open not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662531/window-open-not-working-in-ie)
>   [Javascript “window.open” code won't work in Internet Explorer 7 or 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8)

I have a global detector detecting when someone clicks on an image inside of a `<div>` of class `Gallery` like below:

```
$('.Gallery a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open ($(this).attr('href'),"Gallery Image","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=600");
    });
```

The `event.preventDefault()` is working, so when they click on the image nothing happens. However, in Internet Explorer no window opens.  Any ideas why, or do you know a better way of doing this?

In Firefox / Chrome it works perfectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You can't have spaces in the window name in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662531/window-open-not-working-in-ie), and in fact it only "works" in Firefox/Chrome by fluke: it's not compliant to try to use them.

Note that "name" is not the same as "title" or "caption"; the name should be some programmatic ID like "galleryWindow"; it's not a message that gets displayed to a user anywhere.