# POPUP window issues on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, popup, action

```
$('#order_info_print_confirmation').click(function() {
    var link = 'action_URL' + "?" + $('action_NAME').serialize();
    window.open(link,"Print Confirmation","directories=no,status=yes,width=620, height=900,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

What's wrong here? I'm able to get a popup window with the `printConfirmation` action on Firefox but can't figure it out on IE.

Comment: Can you put a sample up? www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between 'Print Confirmation', make it PrintConfirmation.

```
window.open(link, "PrintConfirmation", "directories=no,status=yes,width=620, height=900,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes");
```

i think this could work

Comment: thanks @Jason.... Now I'm geting popup now but the problem is here `var link = 'action_URL' + "?" + $('action_NAME').serialize();
` I't gives me Error. any thoughts

Comment: Probably right - IE doesn't like spaces in this circumstance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8

Comment: @user1060990 what's the error? note serialize() process all the form elements in it

Comment: Thanks @Jason.., `Problem is I kept some Hidden fields inside div... IE doesn't recognize It so it throws to me error page`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like `action_NAME` is an ID, but you're missing the `#`

```
$('#order_info_print_confirmation').click(function() {
    var link = 'action_URL' + "?" + $('#action_NAME').serialize();
    window.open(link,"Print Confirmation","directories=no,status=yes,width=620, height=900,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

And, is `action_URL` an actual URL or variable?

Comment: action_URL is somthing like.. **PrintConfirmation** Its variable.

Comment: So, another typo? If it's a JS variable then it shouldn't be in quotes. Hard to help when we have to guess at your code!

Comment: ok @paul let me give my working code ` $('#order_info_print_confirmation').click(function() {
      var link = 'printConfirmation' + "?" + $('#confirm_page').serialize();
      window.open(link,"Print Confirmation","directories=no,status=yes,width=620, height=900,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes");

    });`

Comment: its not JS variable It's Back-end Action Variable.