# Window.open without Navigation toolbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am using the below code to open a new popup window without navigation toolbar. But it's open with the navigation toolbar. Please help me to solve my problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl1(newLocation)
{
myRef = window.open('newLocation','mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0,status=0,location=0,address=0');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Popup Script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function popitup(url) {
        newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }       
</script>
```

Then, you link to it by:

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Open popup</a>
```

Here is another reference:

http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Your code working fine in firefox not in ie.

Comment: Have you checked with link provided as it's a cros browser solution.

Comment: yes but i can't do this in ie.That's why am asking this question.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8