# this href open new window not work in ie7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

this href open new window not work in ie7 ? in chrome , firefox and other browser are good, but ie 7 not work , how can i do ?

....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('rated.php','Rated','width=618,height=265')">
    Rated
</a>
```

in chrome , firefox and other browser are good, but ie 7 not work , how can i do ?

Comment: do you get any error in the console ? At first sight, I see no problem with that code.

Comment: is a popup blocker enabled in IE7?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189537/javascript-window-open-code-wont-work-in-internet-explorer-7-or-8) doesn't answer your problem since you don't have a space in any of your parameters, but I'll link to it just in case someone else stumbles across this post and needs a different fix...

Comment: i test click link in ie7 , after clicked it's not open new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a id="my_link">open window</a>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my_link').click(function(){
    $id = $('#id').attr('value');

    window.open("rated.php","rated",
    "menubar=no,width=655,height=280,toolbar=no");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue would seem to be due to the second argument you are passing to `window.open`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to this source, the second argument must specify the name of the window as either `_parent`, `_self`, `_top`, or `_blank`,

Comment: this argument like _blank , can fixed width , height ?

Comment: Yes if you use _blank, it will open in a new window and use the height and width you specify in the third argument